# inspect by 'new' constructed JavaScript object's at the ClojureScript REPL

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop

When I access the following JS object at the ClojureScript REPL I receive this beauty:

```
#object[Url [object Object]]
```

How can I inspect it / see what is inside / convert it to a Clojure data structure?

---

I figured out, that the Clojure REPL only remains as quiet about the object's content when the object was created by a constructor function with JavaScript's new keyword.
(However built-in constructors like Array seem to be an exception)

```
cljs.user=> #js {:a "x"}
#js {:a "x"}

cljs.user=> (defn A [] (this-as my-this (set! (.-a my-this) "x")))
#'cljs.user/A
cljs.user=> (A.)
#object[cljs$user$A [object Object]]
```

This confused me, since - as mentioned in an answer - the browser's REPL (at least chromium and firefox) does print out the content of these objects. Also the Node.js REPL does.
The function js->clj is not helping here. As the code above shows, the Clojure REPL prints even unconverted JavaScript Objects's contents.

Until now I could not find a way to inspect the content as a whole of such  objects. I can only access the properties separately. e.g:

```
cljs.user=> (.-a (A.))
"x"
```

Has by any chance anybody bumped into the same problem and maybe even found a solution or explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was to cast from `#object[Url "..."]` to `#object[Object "..."]`
Finally I did it with this good old helper function.

```
(defn clone-js [jsobj]
  (.parse js/JSON (.stringify js/JSON jsobj)))
```

I'd still appreciate a lot to hear if there are proper solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

Log it in the console and look with chrome/firefox

Comment: it's in a node.js environment

Answer (score 0):

Use [`js->clj`](https://crossclj.info/fun/cljs.core.cljs/js-%3Eclj.html) :

```
(def myobj (js->clj yourJsObj))
```

See [this list](http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/09/12/clojurescript-javascript-interop/) for more interop examples.

Typically, `js->clj` and `clj->js` are helpful for interoping.

Comment: after using js->clj I still get exactly the same output. strange.